# Does RAD Studio (Delphi) support inheritdoc tag?

Tags: delphi, documentation, xml-documentation, rad-studio

Does RAD Studio for Delphi support `<inheritdoc/>` tag for XML documentation.
If yes, how to enable it?

Like in [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#inheritdoc) or [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#@inheritDoc).

I have tried an empty `<inheritdoc/>` and with reference `<inheritdoc cref="InterfaceName.MethodName"/>` with no effect.

Comment: At least it is not listed in the documentation: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/XML_Documentation_Comments